# How to download a PDF locally using angular 2+?

Tags: angular

When I am downloading a PDF it shows download failed in angular 2. I just want to download a pdf from my directory. But this code is not working.

```
<a href="hello.pdf" download> Pdf Download......................... </a>
```

Comment: are you entering correct url in href?

Comment: yes i did but it's not working

Comment: What error do you see in your browser console and w networking tab?

Answer (score 0):

Use HTTP Client

```
getImage(parameters: string) {
  return this.httpClient.get(parameters, { responseType: 'blob' });
}
```

This should download your pdf into browser.

```
getImageFromService() {
this.getImage(this.exportUrl).subscribe(
  data => {
    const file = new Blob([data], { type: 'image/png' });
    const filename = 'example.png';
    const e = this.document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    const a = this.document.createElement('a');

    setTimeout(() => this.loadingExporter = false, 100); // Timeout for better user experiance

    a.download = filename;
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.dataset.downloadurl = ['text/json', a.download, a.href].join(':');
    e.initEvent('click', true, false);
    a.dispatchEvent(e);
  },
  error => {
  });
```

}

Comment: But it show the error like response type is not defined inside getImage function